# Transform attribute vector into a matrix with differences of elements

Tags: r, matrix, vector, similarity, sna

Similarly to this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939675/transform-categorical-attribute-vector-into-similarity-matrix/) I need to transfrom an attribute vector into a matrix. This time with differences between pairs of elements using R.

For example I have a vector which reports the age of N people (from 18 to 90 years). I need to convert this vector into a NxN matrix named A (with people names on rows and columns), where each cell Aij has the value of |age_i-age_j|, representing the absolute difference in age between the two people i and j.

Here is an example with 3 persons, first 18 yo, second 23 yo, third 60 yo, which produce this vector:

```
c(18, 23, 60)
```

I want to transform it into this matrix:

```
A = matrix( c(0, 5, 42, 5, 0, 37, 42, 37, 0), nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tmp <- c(18, 23, 60)
```

You can use `dist` with a couple of arguments:

```
dist(tmp, upper=TRUE, diag=TRUE)
   1  2  3
1  0  5 42
2  5  0 37
3 42 37  0
```

Note that the `dist` function returns a "dist" object, so you might want to coerce it to a matrix with `as.matrix`. Then you can drop the arguments:

```
as.matrix(dist(tmp))
   1  2  3
1  0  5 42
2  5  0 37
3 42 37  0
```

Or again use `outer`. Feed it the  subtraction operator, then take the absolute value.

```
abs(outer(tmp, tmp, "-"))

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    5   42
[2,]    5    0   37
[3,]   42   37    0
```

Presumably, `dist` will be faster than `outer`, since the algorithm can take advantage of the symmetry that is present in such a calculation, while `outer` is more general.

Comment: I'm also wondering if there is an easy way to do the opposite: transform a matrix of distances into an attribute array. Is there a reverse command for outer?

Comment: I can't think of something off the top of my head. This might be worth asking in a separate question. If you do, make sure to include a reproducible example.