# Tranform a matrix of distances into a vector of attributes

Tags: r, matrix, vector, similarity, sna

I am trying to reverse the process presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46956248/transform-attribute-vector-into-a-matrix-with-differences-of-elements).
Specifically, I need to go back to the original vector that generated a matrix of absolute distances between elements.

For example I have a NxN matrix named A (with people names on rows and columns), where each cell Aij has the value of |age_i-age_j|, representing the absolute difference in age between the two people i and j. I need to convert this matrix into a vector which reports the age of this N people.

The matrix could be:

```
A = matrix( c(0, 5, 42, 5, 0, 37, 42, 37, 0), nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)
```

and i want to transform it into this vector:

```
tmp <- c(18, 23, 60)
```

To go from the vector to the matrix I would have used this command:

```
A <- abs(outer(tmp, tmp, "-"))
```

what I'm trying to do is to reverse the process.

Comment: This is mathematically not possible. If you just add any positive integer to your 'tmp' example, you would still get your A matrix.

Comment: Then the problem would be getting to any of the possible vectors which could generate the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, then I will try to answer it. I suggest you first initiate possible vector with any integer

```
seed <- 18
```

then you create your answer

```
answer <- seed + A[,1]
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you. However, this does not seem to work on large matrices where starting values are not integers.. Any idea of why?